# libphonenumber js does not save the cursor position

Tags: javascript, libphonenumber

libphonenumber js does not save the cursor position. Every time I enter or delete a character with the input event, I overwrite value. I understand that because of this, the cursor is placed at the end of the number.
But how can you do it right? I have not found on the Internet that other programmers have problems with this.
What am I doing wrong?
[Example of entering a number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnUZS.gif)

I tried to track cursor changes, but there can be hundreds of number formats, it's hell

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.